# Fastest way to find nearest value in vector

Tags: r

I have two integer/posixct vectors:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15) #has > 2 mil elements
b <- c(4,6,10,16) # 200000 elements
```

Now my resulting vector c should contain for each element of vector a the nearest element of b:

```
c <- c(4,4,4,4,4,6,6,...)
```

I tried it with `apply` and `which.min(abs(a - b))` but it's very very slow.

Is there any more clever way to solve this? Is there a `data.table` solution?

Comment: If it's sorted like in your example it's just one pass through the bigger vector, keeping track of closest element in b manually, otherwise use binary search hinted above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

a=data.table(Value=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15))

a[,merge:=Value]

b=data.table(Value=c(4,6,10,16))

b[,merge:=Value]

setkeyv(a,c('merge'))

setkeyv(b,c('merge'))

Merge_a_b=a[b,roll='nearest']
```

In the Data table when we merge two data table, there is an option called nearest which put all the element in data table `a` to the nearest element in data table `b`. The size of the resultant data table will be equal to the size of `b` (whichever is within the bracket). It requires a common key for merging as usual.

Comment: Welcome to Crossvalidated. Thank you for your answer. Can you extend your answer by explaining the code?

Comment: In Data table when we merge two data table, there is an option called nearest which put all the element in data table a to the nearest element in data table b. Size of the resultant data table will be equal to size of b (which ever is within the bracket). I requires a common key for merging as usual.

Comment: Could you update the answer so that it produces a vector of length `a` as the OP asked?

Answer (score 52):

As it is presented in [this link](http://adomingues.github.io/2015/09/24/finding-closest-element-to-a-number-in-a-list/) you can do either:

```r
which(abs(x - your.number) == min(abs(x - your.number)))
```

or

```r
which.min(abs(x - your.number))
```

where `x` is your **vector** and `your.number` is the value. If you have a matrix or data.frame, simply convert them to numeric vector with appropriate ways and then try this on the resulting numeric **vector**.

For example:

```r
x <- 1:100
your.number <- 21.5
which(abs(x - your.number) == min(abs(x - your.number)))
```

would output:

> ```
> [1] 21 22
> ```

**Update:** Based on the very [kind comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472234/fastest-way-to-find-nearest-value-in-vector/47182392?noredirect=1#comment131877278_47182392) of [hendy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/495990/hendy) I have added the following to make it more clear:

Note that the answer above (i.e `21` and `22`) are the indexes if the items (this is how `which()` works in R), so if you want to get the actual values, you have use these indexes to get the value. Let's have another example:

```r
x <- seq(from = 100, to = 10, by = -5)
x
```

> ```
> [1] 100  95  90  85  80  75  70  65  60  55  50  45  40  35  30  25  20  15  10
> ```

Now let's find the number closest to 42:

```r
your.number <- 42
target.index <- which(abs(x - your.number) == min(abs(x - your.number)))
x[target.index]
```

which would output the "value" we are looking for from the `x` vector:

> ```
> [1] 40
> ```

Comment: Can you extend this easily to have your.number as a vector

Comment: @B.Quaink it logically shouldn't give you the wrong answer as long as you are dealing with Real Numbers. Can you post your numeric vector and your target vector?

Comment: @MehradMahmoudian I converted my matrix to a vector and that seemed to do the trick. I think it took the whole matrix as one instead of looking at each numeric. Thanks

Comment: Just a comment for any who are confused about which.min returning an *index*. I think the problem as asked, and as answered, are slightly ambiguous. The answer says the result should contain "each element of vector"... my face-value read is that an "element" is the "value", not the "index of the value." Due to using vectors where index==value, this might cause confusion.

For example, `x <- c(1, 5, 10, 25, 30)`, `your.number <- 21.5` and `which.min(abs(x - your.number))` will return 4. Just making sure this is clear to readers.

Comment: @Hendy Thanks, I thought it is clear because `which` always returns the index and not the value, and here we are using `which.min` or `which`. Anyways, I can see that this can be confusing for some people, therefore, I have updated the post to reflect your input (and of course with proper credit to you) :) Cheers.

Comment: @Cyrillm_44 I think what you need is a simple sapply: `sapply(your.numberS, function(y){ which(abs(x-y) == min(abs(x-y))) })`

Answer (score 11):

Not quite sure how it will behave with your volume but `cut` is quite fast.

The idea is to cut your vector `a` at the midpoints between the elements of `b`.

**Note that I am assuming the elements in `b` are strictly increasing!**

Something like this:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15) #has > 2 mil elements
b <- c(4,6,10,16) # 200000 elements

cuts <- c(-Inf, b[-1]-diff(b)/2, Inf)
# Will yield: c(-Inf, 5, 8, 13, Inf)

cut(a, breaks=cuts, labels=b)
# [1] 4  4  4  4  4  6  6  6  10 10 10 10 10 16 16
# Levels: 4 6 10 16
```

This is even faster using a lower-level function like `findInterval` (which, again, assumes that breakpoints are non-decreasing).

```
findInterval(a, cuts)
[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4
```

So of course you can do something like:

```
index = findInterval(a, cuts)
b[index]
# [1]  4  4  4  4  6  6  6 10 10 10 10 10 16 16 16
```

Note that you can choose what happens to elements of `a` that are equidistant to an element of `b` by passing the relevant arguments to `cut` (or `findInterval`), see their help page.

Answer (score 5):

For those who would be satisfied with the slow solution:

```
sapply(a, function(a, b) {b[which.min(abs(a-b))]}, b)
```

Comment: The curly brackets are not necessary when the function body consists only of a single expression.

Answer (score 3):

Here might be a simple base R option, using `max.col` + `outer`:

```
b[max.col(-abs(outer(a,b,"-")))]
```

which gives

```
> b[max.col(-abs(outer(a,b,"-")))]
 [1]  4  4  4  4  6  6  6 10 10 10 10 10 16 16 16
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but there is now a function from the `DescTools` package called `Closest` which does almost exactly what you want (it just doesn't do multiple at once)

To get around this we can `lapply` over your `a` list, and find the closest.

```
library(DescTools)

lapply(a, function(i) Closest(x = b, a = i))
```

You might notice that more values are being returned than exist in `a`. This is because `Closest` will return both values if the value you are testing is exactly between two (e.g. 3 is exactly between 1 and 5, so both 1 and 5 would be returned).

To get around this, put either `min` or `max` around the result:

```
lapply(a, function(i) min(Closest(x = b, a = i)))
lapply(a, function(i) max(Closest(x = b, a = i)))
```

Then `unlist` the result to get a plain vector :)

Answer (score 0):

```
# Function
Closest <- function(x, bands) {
  sapply(x, function(y) {
    bands[which.min(abs(bands - y))]
  })
}

# Be aware that when the value is right between to "bands", then the first one is provided
# The lines below don't return the same
Closest(x = c(0, 25000, 25001, 24999, 53000, 159000), bands = c(0, 50000, 100000))
Closest(x = c(0, 25000, 25001, 24999, 53000, 159000), bands = c(100000, 50000, 0))
```