# For each named element in a list, return another named element from the same list based on closeness between element values

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list of entities where each entity has a certain value.

Here is a toy example

```
Lab    Val
A      0.4
B      0.1  
C      0.2
```

For each element in `Lab` (A, B, or C), I want to return the closest entity in the list based on the absolute difference in `Val`. Thus, I would like to have

```
Lab    Val    Neigh
A      0.4    C
B      0.1    C
C      0.2    B
```

`A`'s closest "neighbour" is `C` because 0.4 is closer in terms of absolute difference to 0.2 than it is to 0.1.

For my real example, I generate the list using `split()`. Each `Lab` is a name and each `Val` is a mean of a number of values.

Consider the `eurodist` dataset as a further illustration.

```
data(eurodist)

labs <- labels(eurodist) # get city names
splt <- split(eurodist, labs) # split by city name

splt_mean <- lapply(splt, mean) # calculate mean for each city

splt_mean[1:3]
$Athens
[1] 1395.6

$Barcelona
[1] 1702.8

$Brussels
[1] 1281
```

From the above, `Athens` is "closest" to `Brussels` since the absolute difference is `1395.6 - 1281 = 114.6`. By the same logic, `Barcelona` is closest to `Athens`, and `Brussels` is closest to `Barcelona`.

Using the full dataset, I can further do

```
x <- as.data.frame(splt_mean) # convert to data frame
x <- transpose(x) # transpose dataframe
colnames(x) <- "Mean" # name columns
rownames(x) <- labs # name rows
```

Now, I'd like to add a new column, `Neigh` to `x` containing the name of the closest city based on the scheme descaled above.

```
x[, "Neigh"] <- ... # add new column with closest city
x
                  Mean       Neigh
Athens          1395.6    Brussels
Barcelona       1702.8    Athens
Brussels        1281.0    Barcelona
...             ...       ...
```

What's the best way to get `Neigh`? I know it would be `lapply(splt_mean, ...)`, but how should the function, `FUN`, be specified?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60341501/closest-other-value-in-the-same-vector

Comment: I believe so, but currently trying it on `eurodist`

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a solution, I hope this does the trick.

```
library(data.table) # load package for transpose()

data(eurodist) # load eurodist data

labs <- labels(eurodist) # get city names
splt <- split(eurodist, labs) # split by city name

splt_mean <- lapply(splt, mean) # calculate mean for each city

x <- as.data.frame(splt_mean) # convert to data frame
x <- transpose(x) # transpose dataframe
colnames(x) <- "Mean" # name columns
rownames(x) <- labs # name rows
```

The remaining code below follows from the duplicate question here:

[Closest other Value in the same Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60341501/closest-other-value-in-the-same-vector)

```
d <- data.frame(`diag<-`(as.matrix(dist(x$Mean)), Inf))
ids <- unlist(Map(which.min, d))
Neigh <- x$Mean[ids]
x <- data.frame(labs, x$Mean, Neigh) 
names(x)[1] <- "City"
names(x)[2] <- "Mean"
x[, 3] <- x$City[ids]
```

which gives

```
x
              City   Mean           Neigh
1           Athens 1395.6            Rome
2        Barcelona 1702.8       Stockholm
3         Brussels 1281.0 Hook of Holland
4           Calais 1527.8      Copenhagen
5        Cherbourg 1856.7         Cologne
6          Cologne 1772.5          Munich
7       Copenhagen 1501.1       Gibraltar
8           Geneva 1601.2          Madrid
9        Gibraltar 1479.8           Milan
10         Hamburg 1354.1      Marseilles
11 Hook of Holland 1253.8        Brussels
12          Lisbon 1342.9         Hamburg
13           Lyons 1572.0          Geneva
14          Madrid 1624.5          Geneva
15      Marseilles 1356.0         Hamburg
16           Milan 1475.7       Gibraltar
17          Munich 1770.9         Cologne
18           Paris 1468.4           Milan
19            Rome 1385.4          Athens
20       Stockholm 1672.3       Barcelona
21          Vienna 1213.6 Hook of Holland
```