# Order a list according to multiple columns in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, split

I recently asked, and then answered, my own question after finding out it was a duplicate here:

[For each named element in a list, return another named element from the same list based on closeness between element values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74694464/for-each-named-element-in-a-list-return-another-named-element-from-the-same-lis?noredirect=1#comment131834536_74694464)

There, I used the `eurodist` dataset to find the closest neighbouring city `Neigh` of a city `City` based on the mean distance. I did this using `split()` along with `lapply()`.

```
library(data.table) # load package for transpose()

data(eurodist) # load eurodist data

labs <- labels(eurodist) # get city names
splt <- split(eurodist, labs) # split by city name

splt_mean <- lapply(splt, mean) # calculate mean for each city

x <- as.data.frame(splt_mean) # convert to data frame
x <- transpose(x) # transpose dataframe
colnames(x) <- "Mean" # name columns
rownames(x) <- labs # name rows

d <- data.frame(`diag<-`(as.matrix(dist(x$Mean)), Inf))
ids <- unlist(Map(which.min, d))
Neigh <- x$Mean[ids]
x <- data.frame(labs, x$Mean, Neigh) 
names(x)[1] <- "City"
names(x)[2] <- "Mean"
x[, 3] <- x$City[ids]
```

I've successfully applied the solution to my own data and now have one more step which I'm unable to figure out.

I'd like to `order()` `splt` so that corresponding row elements in `City` and `Neigh` occur together, `City` first followed by `Neigh`. For instance, calling the new list `splt_sort`, I need:

```
splt_sort
$Athens
[1] 3313 1326  966  330 1209 1418  328 2198 2250  618

$Rome
[1] 3927  204  747  789 1497  158  550 1178 2097 2707

...
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll provide an answer to my own question, but @akrun deserves credit.

Their solution was a single line of R code:

```
splt2 <- splt[c(t(x[, c("City", "Neighbour")]))]
```

where `x` is subsetted to extract the `c`oncatenated vector comprising both `City` and `Neighbour` columns, then `t`ransposed and `c`oncatenated a final time before being applied to `splt`.