# Get nearest value in vector prior to specific value

Tags: r

Building on [R - Fastest way to find nearest value in vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472234/r-fastest-way-to-find-nearest-value-in-vector), I am interested in getting the nearest *value* in a vector prior to a specific value.

The `DescTools` package `Closest` does not differentiate according to direction.

Eg.

```
x=c(1,7:10)
min(DescTools::Closest(x, 6, which = F, na.rm = FALSE))
```

would return `7`, while I want `1`. Anyone?

Comment: Is your vector always ordered?

Answer (score 2):

You could try writing a simple function to do this.

```r
closest_preceding <- function(vec, value) max(vec[vec < value])

closest_preceding(x, 6)
#> [1] 1
```